Store-bought corn tortillas have unpleasant, sort-of-floral flavor
I've toasted them in my toaster oven but still the odd flavor remains. I'd rather not throw them out (for $ reasons and eco reasons), and I'm wondering how best to use them. I thought about spreading them with something sweet-ish (cream cheese + crushed berries + sugar) to try to mask the floral flavor; that seems wiser than using them with savory items, such as cheese and garlic, which is what I had hoped to do with them.
If anyone has suggestions, including ways to use them as a base for something savory, I'd be glad to read them. Thank you.

Return the remaining part of the package to the place you bought them. If you opt for replacement rather than refund, look for a different lot number (or expiration date)  at least, or a different brand.

Thank you, Ecnerwal.

“Unpleasant, sort of floral” could describe some fungal growths. I would advise against eating them. Your nose is an important ally in keeping you from poisoning yourself; don’t ignore it.

Thank you, sneftel - I hadn't though about that. Fwiw, I wouldn't have pegged this odor as a sign of decay or fungus -- but I've never purchased corn tortillas before, so I have no idea what they should smell like. Thanks again.
